# Have data as attribute in html and read in ts

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Want to store json data in html dom element and want to read it in function present in ts file.
Tried this:

```
{
  "node": "Node1"
  "checked": false,
  "children": [
     "node": "Node2"
     "checked": false,
     "children": [
        "node": "Node3"
        "checked": false,
        "children": []
    ]
  ]
}

<input [attr.data-myData]="jsonData" (click)="myFunction($event)">

myFunction(event){
}
```

I have to read data attribute, loop through it and make check true for all nodes. Bu it gives me [Object Object] instead of json object.
Tried this:

```
event.target.getAttribute('data-myData')
```

Let me know how best to set and read json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data attribute can have only string as its value, so there is no way to have object in html tag as attribute, unless you convert it to string.
So this is how I achieved it:

```
<input [attr.data-myData]="getStringifiedJsonObj(jsonData)" (click)="myFunction($event)">

In typescript file:

getStringifiedJsonObj(jsonData){
    return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
}
```

In html tag, data attribute is a property binding, and here its value is the returned value of a function call, i.e, the return value of getStringifiedJsonObj function, which here returns stringified json object.
The place where you want to retrieve this value, do getAttribute of the input tag, take out the string object and parse it to get back the object in its original form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Stringify the object to see the actual value.

```
console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-myData'));
```

or access the property using the **`dot`** operator

Comment: Did not work. Can JSON.stringify be used on html [attr.data-myData]="JSON.stringify(jsonData)" ?

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript we do this:

```
JSON.parse(event.target.getAttribute('data-myData'))
```

this returns a "any" object in Typescript which you can traverse with a for..in.. statement.

```
let data = JSON.parse(event.target.getAttribute('data-myData'))
for (let aData in data.children) {
 console.log('checked=' + aData.checked);
}
```

Even better: define a concrete type

Comment: It gives [Object Object] :(